# Oozie variable for all actions

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

Is there a way to set up a global variable for all actions in the workflow?
I need to define variable containing a value and then the same variable will be modified in the actions.

I tried:

```
<workflow-app name="test" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
 <global>
     <configuration>
         <property>
            <name>variable1</name>
            <value>/some/path</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
</global>
.....
 <action name="wf1">
....
  <property>
    <name>variable1</name>
    <value>/some/other/path</value>
  </property>
</action>
....
<action name="wf2">
.....
<property>
    <name>variable1</name>
    <value>/some/second/path</value>
  </property>
....
</action>
<action name="createFolder">
    <fs>
        <mkdir path="${variable1}"/>
    </fs>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
```

I would like to let actions to modified the value and then use it in another action. Is it possible? Right now I´m getting `VARIABLE variable1 cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [action configuration.](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/AG_ActionConfiguration.html)
You can even define default values for each action type.